# Windows Server 2008 local admin - user has limited rights

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions

I have added two domain users to a Win2008 server (non-domain controller) as local administrators.  However these two users still have very limited rights, such as not being able to modify local Internet Security Properties.  Is there another setting overriding their local admin permissions that they are supposed to have?

Comment: Have you any Group Policies in place which may be enforcing these settings?

Comment: This is similar to my question[http://serverfault.com/questions/186039/why-is-using-ntrights-exe-in-windows-server-2008-r2-giving-error-openpolicy-1073]  One way is to turn off UAC but I am waiting for a better answer as well.

Comment: @pratik - you can right click and "Run as Administrator" in order to force elevation. UAC should almost never be disabled.

Comment: In my case I am running a automatic non-interactive build script. There is no way I can "right click".

Comment: gotcha.  will consider instead of permanently lifting restrictions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're "elevating" before doing anything that requires administrative rights. Being a member of the local administrators group means that when you get prompted, it's just to click "Ok" vs. having to provide a separate user name and password.

Comment: You shouldn't disable UAC, instead simply answer the prompt

Comment: Agreed, please don't disable UAC! That can be dangerous. It's really nice to be able to have admin rights and yet not be able to use them by accident.